# Simulating typos in Java without all the busy work

Tags: java, character

How do I simulate natural typos in Java? I was thinking of using a `Map<Character, char[]>` and using a method to iterate through the characters in the string I want to simulate typos in, and then retrieve the values for that character in the map and randomly select one of those. The problem is that it's a lot of work, adding all the characters on the keyboard and then adding its neighbors.

Am on the right path, or is there an easier way?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Couldn't you have done it in the time it took to type this question out? ;)

Comment: To save yourself a little bit of typing (and to avoid mixing generics and arrays), use a `Map<Character,String>`.

Answer (score 5):

I think you've got the right idea already. The only suggestion I would make is that you could auto-generate that map by taking a `String[]` array with the strings "qwertyuiop", "asdfghjkl", and "zxcvbnm" (assuming a QWERTY keyboard) and iterating the characters in each, inserting into the map all the adjacent characters for each key.

**Update**: Then again, [maybe that's more trouble than it's worth](http://ideone.com/A30fA).

Size of Java program to do what I just described: 2,418 characters.
Size of output: 517 characters.

I guess one advantage to doing your solution in code is that it allows you to support more than one keyboard layout.

Comment: Nothing too trivial though, I was going to type that up and thought better of it :)

Comment: Wow, that's useful, lot cleaner looking then my map of 34 entries :D

Answer (score 4):

What is a natural typo and what do you need it for?

You should think of

1. perhaps doubling chars as well, skipping single chars completely
2. missing proper action of shift
3. take into account that if wrong key is pressed, shift status will normally still apply (`@` can be easily mistaken with `W`, not with `w`)
4. do you want to mimic the problem of accidentally hitting capslock instead of tab
5. do you want to mimick dead-key behaviour typo's (in some locale, the IME is set to 'dead-key' compositing, meaning that <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> becomes `á` magically, unless the quote is repeated. This is a genuine source of frequent human typo's

Comment: +1 for the typo typography, I'd add another two: swapped characters, like "teh" or "taht" (a variant of this is eager/late space "myt ypo") and complete hand shift: "logout" -> "kigiyt".